# Getting an id_token using Auth0 in Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, auth0

I’m implementing Auth0 authentication in a new Expo/React Native app following this example:
https://github.com/expo/auth0-example

The only thing I changed is the `scope: 'openid profile'` which in the example is `scope: 'openid name'` though I also tried it with the code in the example.

As you can see in the following screen shot, I’m getting an `access_token` instead of `id_token`:
[image]

Here's the code to authenticate with Auth0:

```
_loginWithAuth0 = async () => {
    const redirectUrl = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
    console.log(`Redirect URL (add this to Auth0): ${redirectUrl}`);
    const result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
      authUrl: `${auth0Domain}/authorize` + toQueryString({
        client_id: auth0ClientId,
        response_type: 'token',
        scope: 'openid profile',
        redirect_uri: redirectUrl,
      }),
    });
    console.log(result);
    if (result.type === 'success') {
      this.handleParams(result.params);
    }
  }
```

I tried changing the `response_type` to `token id_token` but throws an error saying configuration error.

How do I get an `id_token`?

Comment: Can you please supply the configuration error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token returned is defined by the `response_type`, not the `scope`. In the case of the ID token, scope determines what is returned in the token. You need `response_type: 'id_token'`.

You can read more about how it works here: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id-token#control-the-contents-of-an-id-token

Full disclosure, I work for Auth0.